# How to add disappearing and reappearing text on swift

Tags: swift, xcode, click

I'm currently trying to create a [clicker game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_game) which shows how much money you receive when clicking. I'm new to Xcode and swift, but this seems like it should be pretty easy. I would like the score to show how much you earn each time you click it. These labels would appear then disappear quickly. Here is what it would look like:

[image: Clicker Gain Example]

Any and all help in furthering the clicker game (tips, etc.) would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a tap gesture to your view controller and in that UITapGestureRecognizer selector you can do your code to increment count.

Comment: How would I do it with a UIButton

Comment: same thing just use an ibaction for your button instead of screen gesture recognizer